# Який український відповідник для слова match (заметчились)?

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

Ми в IT часто кажемо, що хтось метчиться до команди. Тобто все зійшлось і людина підходить, і з нею гарно працювати. Відбувся метч. Ми з ним заметчились.
Чи є якесь слово, яке б відповідало по сенсу з української мови?

Comment: Складно, запитав [на Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/metch)

Comment: Відбулося співпадіння

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ми з ним заметчились.

*Ми з ним відповідаємо один одному.*

> хтось метчиться до команди

*Він відповідає рівню нашої команди.

Він відповідає нашим запитам.*

Це слово найближче з усього, що є.

Comment: Так, мені теж здається, що IT-шному контексті це найближчий відповідник: «string _s_ matches pattern _p_ (or regular expression _r_)» — «рядок _s_ відповідає шаблону _p_ (чи регулярному виразу _r_)».

Comment: У питанні йдеться про людей, а от щодо цього: мені завжди здавалося, що в цьому випадку "збігається"/"співпадає" найближче (український варіант, на жаль, не завжди добре звучить, на відміну від російського "совпадает").

Comment: oleedd, я можу помилятися, але мені здається, що російське «совпадать» тут не підходить — воно про точний збіг, а не про відповідність шаблону (типу, `^ab{1,3}c$` збігається з `^ab{1,3}c$`, а `abbc` відповідає `^ab{1,3}c$`). Хоча українське «збігатися» має ширший набір значень, ніж російське «совпадать», тож припускаю, що Ви маєте рацію і воно теж підходить… (Хоча я в таких випадках, боячися двозначності, завжди уникав слова «збігатися» і використовував «відповідати», але, можливо, я помилявся.) Так, тут є про що подумати…

Comment: Не сказав би, що ширше, просто "збігатися" має в собі "сбегаться". Теж помітив цей нюанс, але мені здається, що так можна. Звернемося до словників, щоб з'ясувати. У словнику Єфремової є таке значення: *3. Соответствовать чему-либо, согласовываться с чем-либо.* Але чомусь тільки там. У словнику Кузнєцова є таке: *3) Совместиться при наложении.* Коли говорять про регулярні вирази, часто використовують слово "совпадение".

Comment: На справді, я мав на увазі слово match в широкому розумінні. Бо в IT воно прийшло з коду (приклад як писав Sasha з використанням регулярок) і почало використовуватись у широкому вжитку в звичайній мові серед айтішної спільноти.

Answer (score 6):

Ви ж відповіли на своє питання у його описі:
Людина **підходить** команді

Можливі синоніми (взято з [Олександр Пономарів](https://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2015/06/150609_ponomariv_blog58_ko))

> Читач Дейкун цікавиться значеннєвими відтінками слів: личити, пасувати, підхожий, підходящий.
>
> Із цього синонімічного ряду потрібно вилучити останнє слово, бо воно є неоковирною калькою російського подходящий. До його вживання заохочували в ході здійснення політики зближення мов у колишньому Радянському Союзі.
>
> Пасувати – бути прийнятним, годитися, відповідати. Наприклад: "Блакитний капелюшок добре пасував їй до лиця" (Леонід Смілянський).
>
> Личити. Перше значення те саме, що й у слова пасувати. "Ніяк не личить оте чернече вбрання веселій панночці" (Степан Васильченко). Ще одне значення: відповідати встановленим правилам, звичаям. Наприклад: "Співцям співати личить, отже, ми почнем співати" (Леся Українка).
>
> Підхожий – придатний до чогось, такий, що відповідає вимогам. Наприклад: "В обласному центрі мені запропонували підхожу посаду" (з газети).